# Warning al tener multiples SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Tengo este codigo que me crea un cliente, luego de crearlo creo un token para este(token que tiene el id del cliente, por lo que debo hacerlo aparte porque el id lo obtengo cuando se guardar el cliente)

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromForm] ClienteAddRQ clienteAdd)
        {

                 using var dbcontexTransaction = await this._dataContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        Boolean existe = await this._dataContext.Clientes.AnyAsync(cli => cli.Nombre == clienteAdd.Nombre);
                        if (existe == true)
                        {
                            Resp resp = new Resp("Error.Existe", null);
                            return BadRequest(resp);
                    }
                        Cliente cliente = this._mapper.Map<Cliente>(clienteAdd);
                        cliente.Codigo = GenerateRandomString.GenerateString(6);
                        this._dataContext.Clientes.Add(cliente);
                        int resultado = await this._dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        if (resultado == 1)
                        {
                         cliente.Token = this.tokenService.CreateClientToken(cliente.IdCliente, 1);
                         await this._dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                         dbcontexTransaction.Commit();
                     
                         Resp resp = new Resp("Exito.Registro", this._mapper.Map<ClienteRS>(cliente));
                         return Ok(resp);
                        }
                        Resp response = new Resp("Error.Registro", null);
                        return BadRequest(response);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                   {
                        dbcontexTransaction.Rollback();
                        Resp response = new Resp("Error.ServidorCatch", e.Message);
                        return BadRequest(response);
                    }
        }
```

Todo funciona perfectamente, pero al ejecutar el método aparece este mensaje en consola

```
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[30004]
      Savepoints are disabled because Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is enabled. If 'SaveChanges' fails, then the transaction cannot be automatically rolled back to a known clean state. Instead, the transaction should be rolled back by the application before retrying 'SaveChanges'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2149338 for more information. To identify the code which triggers this warning, call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS))'.
```

Comment: Interesante. Cuál es tu pregunta? Y si respondes "cómo hago que desaparezca el warning", te responderemos con otra pregunta: "Qué has investigado?"

Comment: Encontré en git como quitar este warning, para ello colocamos esto en el DbContext

Comment: `         protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(SqlServerEventId.SavepointsDisabledBecauseOfMARS));
        }`